# Delete Magento orders with all related data

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order

I have used an extension to delete some test orders from my Magento Store but while I have checked the data tables all related data to a deleted order was not removed, I have found the Query below where it deletes all the orders with the related data to those orders.

what I am want is to customize it where I can deleted the orders based on the  `order_id` or order `incremental_id`.

I user Magento 1.9.2.4

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `tag`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`; 
TRUNCATE `log_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete order from database then you need to truncate eav_entity_store table and other sales table:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

SALES RELATED TABLES:

```
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;           
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;       
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

DOWNLOADABLE PURCHASED:

```
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;

ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

RESET ID COUNTERS:

```
TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;
ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: I don't want to delete all the orders but specific orders based on the `order_id` or the `order_incremental` number.

Comment: Please see this:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-uHpJ1eOAIXtBQY3_-bwepMyGEmQGPYsAFoiXcLGErM/edit